# How to make the mongoose keys as dynamic dates with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dynamic

I want to make mongoose property names as dynamic dates.
suppose I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
//using moment library below
let date = config.moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  }
  age:{
    type: Number,
  }
 userStream :{ 
    workout: [{
        workout_weeks:{
            type: Number,
        }
//exercise for each day for number of workout_weeks(if workout_weeks = 2, total days = 2*7 =14 thismuch of exercises is needed to be recorded), thats why  we used array of array below.
//also the dates should start from today.
        weeks: [            
          [
            {
              [date]: {
                exercises: {
                type: [String],
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
    }]
 }
});
```

Now, I can get current date for all of them, but I want dynamic dates.
Like the first one should get the date: 2023-07-28,
next one shold get the date 2023-07-29,
then 2023-07-30
and on and on till, (workout_weeks*7)
so that the user when clicks on a specifi, it's easy for me to get user that dates exercise.

```
workout Schema:
const workoutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  workout_weeks:{
    type: Number,
  }
  [date]: {
    exercises: {
      type: String,
    }
  }
 }
);
```

this is the code for enrolling a user:

```
export const enroll = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { workout_id } = req.body;

    const user = await userSchema.findById(id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json(errorResponse("User not found"));
    }

    const workout = await workout_id.findById(program_id)

    if (!workout) {
      return res.status(400).json(errorResponse("Workout not found"));
    }

    user.userStream.workout.push(program);

    await user.save();

    return res
      .status(200)
      .json(sucessResponse("User enrolled successfully", user.userStream));
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json(errorResponse(error?.message || "Something went wrong"));
  }
};
```

I you have any queries regarding feel free to ask!!

Answer (score 0):

On the user Schema just don't define the schema of the property `weeks` this let you add any structure inside the array.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    }
    age: {
        type: Number,
    }
    userStream: {
        workout: [{
            workout_weeks: {
                type: Number,
            },
            weeks: {
                type: Array
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Also the recommended way to push to arrays is the following

```
await user.findOneAndUpdate({id:_id},{
    $push:{
        "workout": program
    }
})
```

But on the workout Schema you can't define "dynamic" properties, that behaviour is only possible on an array.

But the overall design is a little bit odd. i think create a intermediate collection that refers which user workout is and wich routine by _id.